# Is DateTimeControl.IsRequiredField the same asusing the RequiredFieldValidator?

Tags: validation, sharepoint-2010

When using the sharepoint control in VS2010, there is a DateTimeControl with a IsRequired property. Is this the same as using the RequiredFieldValidator?

IsRequired:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="TournamentStartDate" DateOnly="true" IsRequiredField="true" runat="server" />
```

RequiredFieldValidator:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="TournamentStartDate" DateOnly="true" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TournamentStartDateRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TournamentStartDate" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will make it a required field yup ;) What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to know if its treated as a validator in both cases. Whether one is in affect the same as the other

Comment: I'm 99% sure it will but don't have a sharepoint install here to check. A quick way of finding out would be to put a validationsummary on the page and see if the required message finds its way in.